# Provide link to question/answer in Suggested Edits reviews

Tags: support, status-deferred, review-queues, user-interface, suggested-edits

Should we provide a link to the OP in Suggested Edits reviews as in other types of reviews?

I saw reviews where an edit from another user seems to be improving the post. But adding significantly more content/information to the OP. I wasn't sure whether this was moving the comments of the OP into the OP (which would be helpful) or attempt to answer/change of OP intent.

I couldn't find a link to the OP and had to go the front page to find the OP being reviewed.

Comment: You can usually click on the question title to open the question directly.  I can't see what it looks like in a Suggested Edit as there are none to approve right now, but I thought it still give you the different options to show the before/after as it does when you click on "Edited" to show edit history

Comment: @Midavalo, Thanks. I didn't notice the title works as I used the `link` link in other review queues. The review page doesn't show comments in my case, which make it necessary to see the OP.

Comment: Side note: if I am not mistaken OP in SE usually means "original poster" (i.e. the user; not the post itself --> like "original post").

Comment: @AndreSilva You are right. I wasn't able to tell if the Edit was from the comments of the **"original poster"** or the editor. Hence the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feature requests like this should probably be made on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as we don't have the ability to change how SE works here at GIS SE.

That said, you should have a few options already to see the before/after history during a Suggested Edit review.  Have a look at this Suggested Edit I recently reviewed.  The before is on the left, the after (the edit you are reviewing) is on the right.  These two screenshots show the two different options available in the Suggested Edit Review screen.

Markdown output highlighting sections that have been edited, and the specific changes are marked in red (removed) and green (added):
[image]

Rendered output showing just the changes in red and green:
[image]

If you need to get to the original post, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on the Question title - *Inward buffering using QGIS* in this example - which will open a new tab to that Question.
[image]